# Regex: How to get Value After a Specific Pattern Has been Repeated N times

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a file as the example below:

```
OTHERSTRING
orderCasa={"VARIABLESTRING":"VARIABLESTRING|VARIABLESTRING|VARIABLESTRING|VARIABLESTRING|VARIABLESTRING|STRING IM INTERESTED IN (COMPUND BY SIX NUMBERS)|        VARIABLESTRING|VARIABLESTRING|VARIABLESTRING|VARIABLESTRING|VARIABLESTRING|        VARIABLESTRING|
OTHERSTRING
```

where:

1. OTHERSTRING represents any string.
2. VARIABLESTRING represents any string.
3. STRING IM INTERESTED IN (COMPUND BY SIX NUMBERS) is the string i'm interested in, it is compound by 6 numbers and the position is fixed: it comes after five "|".
4. The software i'm using is Jmeter

Comment: yes always 6 numbers but please consider that even the other string can be compound by six numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using **`JMeter`**, I recommend using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor).

```
Reference Name: MYSTR
Regular Expression: \|(.*?)\|
Template: $1$
Match No.: 3
```

With giving a **Match No**. you can use the corresponding *variable* to access the match. `${MYSTR_3}`

```
0 = Random Match
1 = First Match 
2 = Second Match
3 = Third Match
```

The *variables* are set as follows:

```
MYSTR_matchNr - Number of matches found, possibly 0
MYSTR_n       - (n = 1, 2, etc..) Generated by the template
MYSTR_n_gm    - (m = 0, 1, 2) Groups for the match (n) 
MYSTR         - By itself it is always set to the default value
MYSTR_gn      - Not set at all
```